# cutting a particular part of a line without using grep command

Tags: shell, unix, cut

```
RPO.RE4_SND_MSG_RECO_Q_n_message
```

i have an line like this. I would like to cut till `RPO.RE4_SND_MSG_RECO_Q` . when i used

```
cut -d '_' _f4
```

it gave oly RECO as output .please help me Newbie to unix

Comment: As seen in comments, the requirement may vary. Can you update with proper sample input and desired output on representative cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
s='RPO.RE4_SND_MSG_RECO_Q_n_message'
cut -d_ -f1-5 <<< "$s"
RPO.RE4_SND_MSG_RECO_Q
```

Comment: but in some cases the fields may vary .so it wont work that time .

Comment: Does your question cover/specify this varying requirement?